# Adding a space between "push" and parenthesis causes an error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I accidentally added a space between the push method of the array and its parameter, so I got this:

```
def add_credit(description, amount)
    @credits.push ( description: description, amount: amount )
end
```

and it caused an error: `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL @credits.push ( description: description, amount: amount ) ^`

After I removed the space after "push", it was gone. How the space affects syntax in Ruby?

Comment: I can say that Ruby's interpreter is flexible on the use of `( )` and, because of this, will sometimes interpret whitespace. e.g., it would have been valid for you to write `@credits.push description: description, amount: amount` and ruby would add in the `()` for you. I'm guessing that that same parsing logic (that would add the parenthesis in that case) is being confused by your use of parenthesis and a space. Traditionally, the method would be written as `@credits.push()`. I'll also point out that you're using a hash and omitting the `{ }` --> which ruby is adding

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that Ruby interpreter can not figure out if that's a method's braces or argument's.

For example, if you pass an argument with a "simple" syntax to your method, it would work just fine:

```
[1, 2].include? 1        # => true
[1, 2].include? (1)      # => true
[1, 2].include? ( [ ] )  # => true
```

Ruby interpreter could guess that those braces belong to method.

But, if you try to pass an argument that does not have a "simple" syntax, for example a hash (`a: 1`) or a range (`(1..2)`), that would cause an error:

```
[1, 2].include?(a: 1)    # => false
[1, 2].include? ({a: 1}) # => false
[1, 2].include? (a: 1)   # => SyntaxError: (irb):21: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
[1, 2].include? (1..2)   # => false
```

Since Ruby interpreter would now think that you are trying to pass a `Range` as an argument. And, `key: 'value'` syntax is not a valid Range definition syntax.

So, Ruby interpreter is asking you to be clear with braces and help it to clearly identify, if it is a method's braces or argument's. Because, with a space, you are passing a `Range`. See the last line.

Comment: I agree with you.  However, in your 2nd set of statements, only `[1, 2].include? (a: 1)` illustrates the issue; the others behave identically with and without the space.  (The last statement using a range, for example, will return false with or without the space.).  BTW, here is an example of how the behavior differs with and without the space: https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/be8f16f06612603fc352fa0c37d86d53.

Comment: Exactly. As you may see, there is a return value to the right of each statement, showing which statement is OK and which isn't. I am showing that one case when interpreter can't "guess" correctly. Other times, it can correctly guess.